# Fractional Distillation

Tags: experimental-chemistry, mixtures, distillation

Why does the long length of the fractionating column in fractional distillation enable more effective separation of two liquids in a mixture?

(basically what's the purpose of the fractionating column being long in relation to the effectiveness of the fractional distillation process)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply spreads the temperature change over a longer distance, enabling separation of distillates with boiling points close to each other. ["Generally the component parts boil at less than 25 °C from each other under a pressure of one atmosphere."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_distillation)

Imaging reading a mercury thermometer one cm tall as compared with one 100 cm tall: it would be difficult to distinguish temperatures on the smaller one. In the fractionation column below, it helps keep the outputs separate.

[image: Fractionation Column]